# haskell another function as input parameter

Tags: haskell

hi_copy.hs

```
waxOn = x
    where 
        z = 7
        y = z + 18
        k = y ^ 2
        x = k * 5

triple  = a
    where 
        a = a * 3
```

then load.

```
ghci> :load hi_copy.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hi_copy.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
```

then run
`triple waxOn`

```
<interactive>:122:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’
                  with actual type ‘Integer’
    • The function ‘triple’ is applied to one value argument,
        but its type ‘Integer’ has none
      In the expression: triple waxOn
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = triple waxOn
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:122:1)
```

run `3 * waxOn` will work.
but now I don't how to make `triple waxOn` working.
meta: till now still not learning type in haskell. There maybe other good answers already exists. But I don't understand other people's great answer.

Comment: `triple` does not take a parameter. You made an endless recursive function where `a` is `(((((...) * 3) * 3) * 3)`.

Comment: `triple x = x * 3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `triple` does not take any parameter. It only returns a value, a value that will be the result of endless recursion where `a` is `((((…) * 3) * 3) * 3)`.

You should take as input a parameter, so:

```
triple :: Num a => a -> a
triple a = a * 3
```

or shorter:

```
triple :: Num a => a -> a
triple = (3 *)
```

Comment: `triple :: Num a => a -> a`  after sometime learning will be solved. for now `triple a = a * 3` solved my problem.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `(* 3)`, since `a * 3 == 3 * a` isn't guaranteed to be true for all `Num a => a` :)